# Schematic review /suggestions: Driving a relay with an Arduino

Tags: arduino, transistors, diodes, analog, relay

I am using an Arduino Nano to drive this [G5NB-1A-E DC5](https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-g5nb.pdf) relay. My circuit is given below.

The BJT (MMSS8050-H) is [this one](https://www.mccsemi.com/pdf/Products/MMSS8050(SOT-23).pdf).

Is this circuit OK? V_CHIP_REL1_EN is from an Arduino Nano.

What things need to be considered for the PCB layout?

As far as I know, a relay needs a solid return path, and there should be no trace routed below the relay.

[image]

Comment: Please explain this: *As far as I know, a relay needs a solid return path, and there should be no trace routed below the relay.*

Comment: I doubt if we route traces under relay,the electromagnetic energy from relay coil will couple to the trace.Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: It sounds like wrong thinking to me. What about the "*solid return path*" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: Soild Return path means Ground plane.Is the above circuit fine

Comment: Relays don't need a ground plane and the EM energy from the coil will barely affect anything.

Comment: Thank you Andy.May I know the above circuit is fine or not

Comment: "No trace under the relay" is most likely for isolation, if the relay switches mains voltage it is best to keep signal low voltage traces away from the high voltage pins. Especially ground plane should be away from the mains voltage pins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Thank you Andy. May I know the above circuit is fine or not*

The Nano can supply a logic level of 5 volts and, under these circumstances I would be considering driving the BJT with a base current of 4 mA. This is a rule of thumb when trying to use a BJT as a switch; the base current is one-tenth that collector current. This reflects the fact that the beta of a BJT does drop significantly from the hundreds range to below 20 in these circumstances. So, 4 mA base current is what I'd use to guarantee that the BJT drops less than about 0.5 volts when operating with a collector current of 40 mA.

This ensures that the minimum operating voltage for the relay is pretty much guaranteed (3.75 volts or 75% of 5 volts).

Using a 1 kΩ resistor for R42 means that it can produce 5 mA into a short circuit but, due to the presence of R43 means you probably won't quite reach 4 mA. This is because the base-emitter voltage will be about 1 volt. So, i'd probably go for a 680 Ω resistor for R42. If you are really struggling to find the extra current then consider replacing the BJT with a low \$V_{GS(THRES)}\$ MOSFET.

Comment: Thanks, Andy..The diode which I selected is fine here?

Comment: @HARITO the diode is fine - you might have found a cheaper one because it only needs to handle less than 100 mA and its reverse voltage rating needn't be as high as 1,000 volts (100 volts would easily do).

Comment: If Vbe is 1V and Rb is 1K ,Ib will be 4mA as per calculation.May I know why you told it won't reach 4mA due to R43 .Sorry for delayed doubt

Comment: Because the effective Thevenin source voltage will be slightly less than 5 volts i.e. 4.545 volts. Then subtract 1 volt for BE and you are left with 3.545 volts across 1 kohm.

Comment: Thank you. Effective Thevenin Voltage means output voltage of the Arduino nano Gpio. Correct me If I am wrong

Comment: It's the effective open circuit voltage of the 5 volt GPIO pin and the two resistors that form a potential divider.

Comment: OK Vth is 4.54V and Rth is almost 1K. May I know same calculation is Applicable if I directly connect 5V to 1K instead of driving from Arduino

Comment: You'll need to read the arduino data sheet for that information. I don't know what amount of voltage droop you get on an arduino output when driving current.

Comment: If we put 680 ohm Ib will be 5.2mA.Relay coil current Min36ma Typ 40mA, Max 44ma, Here transistor beta is 10 so it will make Ic=52mA.Will that damage the Relay

Comment: No, it cannot supply more current to the relay than what the relay takes when across a 5 volt supply. The transistor saturates and beta drops accordingly. That is why we assume a beta of maybe 10 but, it will become what it needs to be when the transistor saturates.